# How to pass JSP variables to servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I am trying to pass two values from my JSP page to servlet using request dispatcher.

Here is the JSP code:

```
<%
            String companyName = (String) request
                    .getAttribute("adminCompnayName");
            String tenantId = (String) request.getAttribute("adminTenantId");

            request.setAttribute("adminCompnayName", companyName);

            request.setAttribute("adminTenantId", tenantId);

request.setAttribute("adminTenantid","my compnay");
            request.setAttribute("adminCompanyname"," my tenant id");
            String servletName="../StoreUserDetails";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(servletName);
            if (dispatcher != null){
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
```

These two values are received from another servlet.

Here is the servlet code where I am receiving values.

```
String tenantId = (String) request.getAttribute("adminTenantid");
        String companyName = (String) request
                .getAttribute("adminCompanyname");




out.println("--------------------------"
                + request.getAttribute("adminTenantid"));
        out.println("--------------------------"
                + request.getAttribute("adminCompanyname"));
```

But I am getting null values.

```
--------------------------null 

--------------------------null
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You seem to completely misunderstand how to properly use JSP/Servlets.  Your JSP is been used as a controller and your servlet is been used as a view. It should be the other way round. Put your mouse above the `[servlets]` tag which you placed on the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link. Read this carefully and thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

You store the attributes as `adminTenantId` and `adminCompnayName`, and get them in the servlet as `adminTenantid` and `adminCompanyname`. Check the spelling of your attributes, or even better, define constants and use them everywhere, to avoid such typos.

That said, a well designed application should dispatch from a servlet to a JSP, and not from a JSP to a servlet. JSPs should not use scriptlets and should only be used to generate markup using EL, the JSTL and other custom tags.